# C++ compiler which I can bundle with my application

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-construction

I'm working on developing my own programming language, and to generate executables I wished to convert the source to C++ and the run it through a C++ compiler.

Does anybody know of a C++ compiler which I can simply include with my application and then invoke from the command line without installation?

I'm using Windows.

Thanks in advance, Tom.

Edit:
It seems gcc is the way to go and it would be a pain to set up, would people recommend bundling the installation file instead and then installing the compiler as part of the installation of my program?

Comment: Lots of people distribute GCC with their products. It's not a tiny package though.

Comment: Why a C++ compiler specifically? That seems like an awfully fragile way to achieve your goal. Have you considered a more general parser/compiler framework like LLVM?

Comment: There are also some licensing issues - GCC is GPL software. I'm not sure how closely your own stuff will be associated with it, but you may wind up having to GPL your code too.

Comment: @jalf this is only for a small personal project, but thanks I will take a look into that. @neil It's not a commercial product I was planning on making it freely available anyway, but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried gcc (the windows port)?

Comment: I have looked at MinGW but I cannot find a download which is not an installation executable. I may be missing something obvious here, if you can point me towards the correct download page I need then I'll accept this answer :)

Comment: There is more than one Windows port of gcc. The most famous ports are Cygwin and MinGW, the later is probably more reasonable for bundling, but it can still be a bit of a headache to setup.

Comment: I believe you can just install it on your PC and then just use the executable alone -- that used to be the case (well a while back).

Comment: You can install it on your own machine and then just create a zip of the installation. The best version to use is the one from http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net - on no account try to use the one from the MinGW page.

Comment: @Neil thanks, that seemed to be exactly what I was looking for, If you write this as an answer I will accept. Thanks to everyone else too :)